# Valor de teste javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Eu estou tentando retornar true ou false

```
{{ !form.tel_numero.length >= 9 }}
```

Não está funcionando

Se eu não utilizo negação funciona

```
{{ form.tel_numero.length >= 9 }}
```

mas, eu preciso da negação

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente é isto:

```
{{ !(form.tel_numero.length >= 9) }}
```

Pois se não usa os parenteses para isolar, o `!` acaba tornando o `form.tel_numero.length` em um valor booleano, true ou false, e então ele compara true ou false com `>= 9` o que seria algo como:

```
true >= 9
```

ou:

```
false >= 9
```

Já quando aplica o parenteses ele primeiro resolve o que esta dentro do parenteses e depois irá aplicar a negação do `!`

Outra maneira de se fazer isso é fazer a condição ao contrário, se `form.tel_numero.length >= 9` significa que `form.tel_numero.length` tem que ser maior ou igual a 9, então o contrário disto seria que `form.tel_numero.length` tem que ser menor que 9, assim:

```
{{ form.tel_numero.length < 9 }}
```

Note que se retornar `0` ele vai entrar na condição também.